# PHP, MYSQL noob joining(?) tables specifics

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and am making a social network as practice and to apply what I have learned in the "real world".  Anyhow, I have two tables in a MySQL database that i am trying to display on my site in the same html table that is being rendered through an php echo.

here are the tables

(table1) 
note_system:
-id,
-username,
-note

(table2)
comments:
-id,
-cid (equals id from note_system),
-username,
-comment

so someone makes a post and it saves to the note_system table then someone comments on the post and it saves to the comment table with the id from the note_system table so a relation can be established.

So what I am trying to do is get the post comments to display with the relevant post.  I have gathered that I need maybe a JOIN or UNION to make this happen but I am at a complete loss on how to do it.  Been racking my brain and doing tons of google searches but I am not really getting anywhere.  Everything I try gives me errors.  The Notes display just fine and as intended but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the comments to show up there too.

Here is my code  (don't laugh at the noob-ness of my PHP, this is my 2nd PHP program ever and I obviously have much to learn, I would like to clean it up at some point but for now I just want it to be functional)

```
<?php
// Display Note_Wire

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}   


//format and display the Note_Wire results with comments

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM note_system");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<center>";
echo "<table class='note_wire'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>" ;
echo "</tr><tr>";

echo "<td><a href=''>vote up</a>" . "  " . $row['rank'] . "  " . "<a href=''>vote      down</a></td>" ;
echo "</tr><tr>";

echo "<td> <a href='{$row['link']}' target='blank'>{$row['link']}</a>";
echo "</tr><tr>";


echo "<td>" . $row['note'] . "</td>" ;

echo "</tr> ";



//add comments attempt  this is where I would like the comments to be displayed

echo  '

<td><form action="add_comment.php" method="POST">  

<input type="hidden" name="username" value="';

echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo '" />'; 

echo '<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="';
echo $row['id']; 
echo '" />'; 

echo '<textarea name="comment">comment...</textarea></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="submit" value="comment" />

</form></td></tr>


';







echo "</table>";




// break before next note-wire record renders
echo "<br />";

}



echo "</center>";








 ?>
```

I hope my chicken scratch programming makes sense.  Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Comment: where is the code for database????

Comment: Kaii- There is no error with this code.  I need to add code to make it completely functional.  I am displaying content from one table in the database fine but i would like to display content from a second table that is related to the first table.

Comment: shewt dalal- I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: you need to add the SECOND  phase mentioned below .. the query..

Comment: If you know the `id` of the note you are displaying, then use the query to select the comments associated with it.  If you want to get the note content as well as all the comments, doing so in one query will return a lot more data than you truly need (as you'd select the note content with every comment), so you should focus on them separately.

Comment: Kaii-  Thanks, The second Phase somehow didn't make into my copy and paste of the code, I just edited the code to include it, not sure why it didn't paste in the first place but it is there now.

Comment: Jon-   Thanks.  I do know the id of the displayed note and I have that saved to the comment table when someone posts a comment.  The note id is saved in the comment table as the cid.         " then use the query to select the comments associated with it. "   that is exactly what I am asking help with.  can't figure out how to create a query that does that.

Comment: @ButterDog `select * from comments where cid=myNoteID` and change `myNoteID` to the ID of the note you are using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the comments are a different data set from the actual post you could just use a second query to get all of the comments related to the post. But table joins are very useful and you should learn them. In this case you would join the note_system and comments table on the shared ID (the foreign key).

So like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM note_system
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.cid=note_system.id
```

This is a literal joining of the tables so your output will include all columsn from both tables as long as there is a match for the joining expression. If there isn't a CID column in the comments table that matches then the values for those columns will be NULL in your output. (If you wanted to only return rows where there is a match you could use an INNER join as opposed to the LEFT OUTER join I've used above.)

[This is a good page explaining SQL table joins.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: RealityGone-  Thanks for the tip!  I am going to go give that a shot once I get through reading your link.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You could also use a UNION statement to put the comments into the same dataset as the original note, and then you wouldn't have a dataset with the note contents on every row (which is basically what you'd be getting with a join). But I still think it would probably be best to just use a second query. You just stick a UNION statement in between two SQL statements and it will stick them together like they were all from a single query. You just have to make sure that both SQL statements return the same number of columns of the same data types.

Comment: EUREKA!!!!   I can't believe how simple that was!  Thank you so much.  I have been killing myself with this for hours, I read your answer and 10 minutes later my code makes perfect sense and functions exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will look into UNION as well as give that a thought when I get around to making the code more efficient, clean, etc...   I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Heres the basics step for you if your a beginner in using php and mysql..

FIRST : SET UP CONFIGURATION FOR DATABASE USER,PASS,HOST,DBNAME

```
$conn = new mysqli('database_server','database_username','database_password','database_name');
```

SECOND : Create a Query(you may insert your query here)..

```
$result= $conn->query("SELECT SUM(Total_Steps) AS value_sum FROM users");
```

FINAL : SHOWN RECORDS USING MYSQL FUNCTIONS LIKE..

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['dabatase_columnname'];
    echo $row['database_columnname'];
}
```

for your query try to use this one or either create a relative one.

`SELECT 'enter column needed here with their specific database allias ex. TABLE1.ID'FROM NOTE_SYSTEM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN COMMENTS TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.CID;`

Comment: Thanks Kaii, I appreciate you taking the time to explain but my trouble is not displaying data from a  database but rather displaying data from two tables in the database in the same query where the second table displays based from a relation to the first table.  I am probably not explaining this well as my programming vocabulary is rudimentary

Comment: @ButterDog does this means what u need is the query one? :)

Comment: Kaii-  Thanks for the assistance.  I am not sure what you are asking exactly.  What I am trying my hardest to figure out is how I can get my query to display the note from table one AND the realted comment from table two.  I have passed the note id to the comment table but can't figure out how to write the query to display both.

Comment: `SELECT 'enter column needed here with their specific database allias ex. TABLE1.ID'FROM  NOTE_SYSTEM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN COMMENTS TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.CID;`